# Telerik TreeView for ASP.NET MVC ajax woes

Tags: asp.net, jquery, treeview, telerik, partial-views

Telerik's TreeView control, although fancy and with a lot of functionality is proving to be a nightmare for me now. However I could not find a better TreeView control which supports collapsing/expanding etc. and has a little bit of documentation. Here's my problem.

This is the site master : _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <!--
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
    @(Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
                    .DefaultGroup(group => 
                        group.Add("telerik.common.css")
                             .Add("~/Content/Site.css")
                             .Add("~/Content/custom.css")
                             .Add("~/Content/themes/humanity/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css")
                    .Combined(true)
                    .Compress(true)))
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="header-logo">
                    <img alt="X" src="../../Content/Images/logo100.png"/>
            </div>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>title</h1>
            </div>

            @(Html.Telerik().Menu()
                    .Name("menu")
                    .Items(menu =>
                    {
                        menu.Add().Text("Home").Action("Index", "Home");
                        menu.Add().Text("Products")
                            .Items(item =>
                                       {
                                           item.Add().Text("xxx").Action("xxx", "Products");
                                           item.Add().Text("xxx").Action("xxx", "Products");
                                           item.Add().Text("xxx").Action("xxx", "Products");
                                           item.Add().Text("xxx").Action("xxx", "Products");
                                       });
                        menu.Add().Text("Events").Action("Index", "Events");
                        menu.Add().Text("About Us").Action("About", "Home");
                        menu.Add().Text("Admin").Action("Index", "Admin");
                    })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left;" }))
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
                        .Scripts(script=>script.Add("~/Scripts/custom.js"))
                        .Globalization(true)
                        .DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true)
                                                    .Compress(true)))
</body>
</html>
```

This is the base page view : Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin";
}
<h2>
    Admin Index</h2>
<div id="navAdminLeft">
    @(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("AdminNavTree")
    .Items(item =>
               {
                   item.Add().Text("Products");
                   item.Add().Text("Categories");
                   item.Add().Text("Materials");
                   item.Add().Text("Finishes");
                   item.Add().Text("Packaging");
                   item.Add().Text("File Manager");
                   item.Add().Text("CategoryTree");
               })
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnSelect("loadAdminContent"))
           )
</div>
<div id="adminContent">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadAdminContent(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "Admin/" + e.item.innerText,
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#adminContent").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

whenever the user selects a node on the `#AdminNavTree` the page fetches the content to be displayed and populates `#adminContent`. I am trying to build an edit page where there is a category tree listed in one div and when the user clicks on any of the category on that div, the details are ajax loaded into another div on the same page. Here is the partial view with the category tree that gets loaded into `#adminContent`: _CategoryTree.cshtml

```
@using xxx.Models.Navigation
@model IEnumerable<NavigationItem>

<div id="categoryTree">      
 @{Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("ctree")
        .BindTo(Model, mappings => 
            mappings.For<NavigationItem>(binding => binding
                    .ItemDataBound((currentItem, navigationItem) =>
                        {
                            currentItem.Text = navigationItem.Text;
                            currentItem.Expanded = true;
                                                        })
                    .Children(child => child.Items)

                ))
    .ClientEvents(events=>events.OnSelect("loadContent"))                                  
    .Render();
}
</div>
<div id="detail"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadCategoryDetail(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Admin/CategoryDetails",
            data: { id: $("#ctree").data("tTreeView").getItemText(e.item) },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#detail").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

the detail page that is ajax loaded does not contain any telerik controls so listing code for that is a non issue.

The PROBLEM : this will not render. As soon as it tries rendering `#ctree` treeview it starts throwing all kind of script errors, specifically it ignores loadCategories (says not found). So far I think what is happening is the ajax loaded partial page that contains the treeview is reloading the jquery lib destroying all old bindings and functions in the script. Is there a way to make this work, two treeviews on one page, one previously loaded, one in a ajax loaded partial view, both binding to separate data?

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with jsTree... doesn't help with your telerik question, but might be worth checking out.

http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: The documentation is pretty decent, and the google group has a lot of answers.

Comment: i've been working with that on the side. using json_data pulling data via ajax request. Haven't quite ironed out the issues with my server side json code yet.